Conformal equivalence from $D = \{z : 0 < \arg z < 3\pi / 2\}$ to $S = \{z: 0 < \Im z < 1\}$
I would like to verify if the conformal equivalence from $D = \{z : 0 < \arg z < 3\pi / 2\}$ to $S = \{z: 0 < \Im z < 1\}$ I have found is correct.
First, consider the map $f: D\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z) = z^{2/3}$, where we choose $\arg z \in (0, 2\pi)$. $f$ can be equivalently written as $f(z) = |z|^{2/3}e^{i\cdot \frac{2}{3}\arg z}$. So for $z\in D$, since $0< \arg z < 3\pi / 2$, we have $0 < \frac{2}{3}\arg z < \pi$. From this, we then see that $f$ is a conformal equivalence from $D$ to $\mathbb{H} = \{z: \Im z > 0\}$.
We can then use the Cayley transform $g: \mathbb{H}\to D(0,1)$ given by $g(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$.
Finally, since $z\mapsto e^{iz}$ is a conformal map from $S$ to $D(0,1)$, we can consider the inverse map $z\mapsto -i \log z$ as this shall then be a conformal map from $D(0,1)$ to $S$.
Putting this all together, I have that $$D\xrightarrow{z\mapsto z^{2/3}}\mathbb{H} \xrightarrow{z\mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}}D(0,1) \xrightarrow{z\mapsto -i\log z}S$$ is my conformal map.

This looks pretty promising to me;   but wait for an expert.    I fixed a typo (I think).
